# Turning off the auto-capitalization of the initial character of the keyboard in iOS? Flutter

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm using Flutter, and I'm building a login screen. The default behavior of the keyboard on iOS seems to auto-uppercase the initial character. I'd like to turn that off. How do I do it?

Answer (score 3):

iOS auto-capitalizes the first letter when a word is a proper noun, e.g. Matt or Brazil.

So, when you type a dot in an email address, you are effectively creating a word and iOS wants to "correct" it.

You can turn this off with

```
autocorrect: false
```

in a `TextField` or `TextFormField` widget.

Answer (score 2):

Capitalization in text fields is now disabled by default and can be configured via `textCapitalization` property:

```
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

TextField(...
  textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.words
..)
```

— [@dmjones, flutter/flutter](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/10632#issuecomment-408657077)

Answer (score 1):

The `UITextAutocapitalizationType` is set in [`FlutterTextInputPlugin`](https://github.com/flutter/engine/blob/master/shell/platform/darwin/ios/framework/Source/FlutterTextInputPlugin.mm). Currently it isn't configurable and it defaults to `UITextAutocapitalizationTypeSentences` if the type of the field is `TextInputType.text` and `UITextAutocapitalizationTypeNone` otherwise.

So basically, you can change the text input type to `TextInputType.emailAddress` or `TextInputType.url` and it won't be capitalized. If that isn't enough configurability for you, you'd have to change the Flutter engine.

Comment: Thanks! I opened https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/10632 to make this configurable.